# What is the cause of the "No Data" error when backtesting in Trading View Strategy Tester written in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I wrote a strategy in Pine Script in order to backtest it on Trading View. It seems it compiles with no error but when backtesting it says "No Data". I can't figure out what is wrong with my code and I will show to you. I'm still new to coding and pine editor I don't know how to fix this error I've tried everything I can think of if anyone can take a look at my code and provide some insight on how I can improve it.

```
//@version=5
strategy("MACD-ATR-Trailing-Stop with UT Bot Alerts", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000)

// Indicator: MACD
fast_length = input.int(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input.int(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Length", defval=9)

fast_ma = ta.ema(close, fast_length)
slow_ma = ta.ema(close, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
histogram = macd - signal

// Indicator: ATR Trailing Stop with UT Bot Alerts
a = input.float(title='Key Value. This changes the sensitivity', defval=1, minval=0.01, maxval=100, step=0.01)
c = input.int(title='ATR Period', defval=10, minval=1, step=1)
h = input.bool(title='Signals from Heikin Ashi Candles', defval=false)

xATR = ta.atr(c)
nLoss = a * xATR

// Custom Heikin Ashi implementation
ha_open = (open + close) / 2
ha_high = math.max(math.max(high, ha_open), close)
ha_low = math.min(math.min(low, ha_open), close)
ha_close = (open + high + low + close) / 4

src = h ? ha_close : close

// Trailing stop at local high and local low
long_stop = ta.highest(src, length = 20)
short_stop = ta.lowest(src, length = 20)

xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
iff_1 = src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.max(long_stop, src - nLoss) : src + nLoss
iff_2 = src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.min(short_stop, nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]) + nLoss) : iff_1
xATRTrailingStop := src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.max(nz(long_stop), src - nLoss) : iff_2

// Indicator: RSI
rsi_length = input.int(title="RSI Length", defval=14)
overbought = input.int(title="Overbought Level", defval=75)
oversold = input.int(title="Oversold Level", defval=25)

rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)

// Moving Averages
ma13 = ta.ema(src, 13)
ma34 = ta.ema(src, 34)

// Define take profit target
stop_loss = close * 0.1
take_profit = stop_loss * 3

// Enter Long Trade When RSI is Under 25 and Price is Above Trailing Stop and Above MA13 and MA13 is Above MA34
long_condition = rsi < oversold and src > xATRTrailingStop and src > ma13 and ma13 > ma34
if long_condition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Exit Long Trade When Price Crosses Below MA13 or Trailing Stop
var stop_price = 0.0
if (src < xATRTrailingStop)
    stop_price := xATRTrailingStop
else if (src < ma13)
    stop_price := ma13
else
    stop_price := close - stop_loss

strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", stop=stop_price)
```

I don't know what to try but I'm expecting some results at least

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on EUR/USD from OANDA and it doesn't throw any error.
I think your code is ok, try changing the source of your data, this error message seems to try to tell you that the provider of the data (it can be Bitsamt, oanda, fxm ...) did not sent any data.